# How to correct the IndexError

Tags: python, scikit-learn

*Using the Logistic regression algorithm implemented by the Python Scikit-learn, classify the three types of flowers (Setosa, Versicolor, Virgin) in Iris dataset according to the Petal length and width.*

**May I know how to correct the coding as refer to attached file -**

```
from sklearn import datasets

#load data
iris=datasets.load_iris()
X=iris.data[:,[2,3]]
y=iris.target
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=0,stratify=y)
#feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std=sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std=sc.transform(X_test)
#Logistic regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
C1=[]
A=[]
C1=[0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]
for i in range(len(C1)):
    lr=LogisticRegression(C=C1[i], random_state=0)
    lr.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
    y_pred=lr.predict(X_test_std)
    A[i].append(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

#draw figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(C1,A)
plt.title('Logistic Regression')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()
```

Please see the picture - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylH0w.jpg)
    .

**Here is the error -**

```
runfile('C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/testttttttttttttttttt.py', wdir='C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop')
Reloaded modules: __mp_main__
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-94a347d3dde0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/testttttttttttttttttt.py', wdir='C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\HSIPL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HSIPL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/HSIPL/Desktop/testttttttttttttttttt.py", line 26, in <module>
    A[i].append(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

By executing `A[i].append(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))`, you are saying that `A` itself contains `lists` and attempting to append one score to each of them.

However, `A` is an empty `list`, and accordingly you just want `A.append(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))`

Comment: Your answer is correct but the picture is still wrong - tell me what happen ?

Comment: @vokoyo what do you mean by "wrong"? Please provide your expected output.

Comment: Please see the picture - link above

Comment: Please see the picture - enter image description here

Comment: Do you see that image file ?

Comment: @vokoyo That is because the scales of your provided plot (logarithmic) and your actual plot (linear) are different. As that would be out of scope of this question, I would suggest that you ask a new question.

Comment: Can you please help me by write some useful solution - I cannot understand how to draw

Comment: @vokoyo as my answer has solved the problem that you faced, please accept it. Again, you should ask a new question regarding the scale of the graph, since that is a *different* issue from the topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

**main**: issue was near `train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=0)` you need not to do `stratified sampling`

**other**: you need to change scale to `log`. and `A.append` in place of `A[i].append`

```
from sklearn import datasets

import numpy as np
#load data
iris=datasets.load_iris()
X=iris.data[:,[2,3]]
y=iris.target
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
#feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std=sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std=sc.transform(X_test)
#Logistic regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
A=[]
C1=[0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000]
for i in range(len(C1)):
    lr=LogisticRegression(C=C1[i], random_state=0)
    lr.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
    y_pred=lr.predict(X_test_std)
    A.append(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

#draw figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(C1,A)
ax.set_xscale("log")
new_tick_label  = ['{:1.2f}'.format(x) for x in C1]
ax.set_xticks(C1)
ax.set_xticklabels(new_tick_label)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(.6,1.01,.05))
plt.grid(True)

plt.title('Logistic Regression')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get the picture but still not very same as the attached image - why ?

Comment: @vokoyo please check the updates now and accept answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: May I get your contact email ?